# Shortcode strips formatting and returns at content top

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

Using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and I've got a shortcode going for a repeater field, but it returns the list at the content top. I changed it from an `echo` to a `return`, which I understood would fix the issue of it appearing at the top of the content, but it didn't and now it strips all the html out and returns the whole thing as one big text block. Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

```
function teamlist_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
if (get_field('aw_team_members')):
while (has_sub_field('aw_team_members')):

$string = '<h3>' . the_sub_field('team_name') . '</h3><h3 class="subtitle">' . the_sub_field('team_title') . '</h3>' . the_sub_field('team_bio');

endwhile;
return $string;
endif; 
}
add_shortcode('teamlist', 'teamlist_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_sub_field` `echo`s content. The docs are quite clear about that.

> The the_sub_field function is used with the repeater field and the
>   flexible content field (license key required) to display a sub field
>   value. When looping through one of these fields, this function
>   displays a sub field from the current row.
>
> This is the same as echo get_sub_field();
>
> http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_sub_field/

Use [`get_sub_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_sub_field/) to construct a string.

The function names follow a common (but not universal) WordPress pattern or use the `the_` prefix for functions that `echo` and the `get_` prefix for functions that return.

However, there will still be a problem in that your code completely overwrites `$string` at each iteration. You need to concatenate a string with all of the results, which you can do easily with `.=` instead of just `=`.

```
function teamlist_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
  if (get_field('aw_team_members')):
    $string = '';
    while (has_sub_field('aw_team_members')):
      $string .= '<h3>' . the_sub_field('team_name') . '</h3><h3 class="subtitle">' . the_sub_field('team_title') . '</h3>' . the_sub_field('team_bio');
    endwhile;
    return $string;
  endif; 
}
add_shortcode('teamlist', 'teamlist_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I had forgotten about that. Unfortunately, now it only returns the last entry in the repeater field, so I still have something wrong.

Comment: @Christopher : You are overwriting the string at each iteration of the loop. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you dearly. Still so much to learn. That was an enormous help.